# How can i make my background look like the one in the image in css3?

Tags: css, sass, background

I am new to web development. I am trying to put an app together. I don't know how i can achieve the background like in the image.

[image]

I already tried linear-gradient with some angles but that did not help.

If anyone want's to know what property i used than it would be the one mentioned below:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, red, blue);
```

Comment: Can you show the image?

Comment: please also post the image

Comment: sorry about that..

Comment: Can you share the code? You are using this as background image on the body or a div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to get something like this?

```css
body{
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, #9999FF 0%, #9999FF 50%, white 50%, white 100%);
}
```

```html
<body>
<h1>Some dumy text...</h1>
</body>
```

**How it works**
In your background you can use linear-gradient, in this you can tell what direction it goes. In this example I  use "to top right", this makes it so the starting color starts in bottom-left and the end color goes to the top-right.

You could use all kind of directions like "to bottom right" or "to right".

Then you say what color you want it to start with, in this example its some blue color. Then you tell it when it should stop using this blue color, in this example 50%. Then if you want the white color on the other side you say "white 50%" and it will start using white till 100%.

You could also try some other cool things with it. You can say for example `linear-gradient(to top right, blue 0%, blue 40%, white 60%, white 100%)`
notice that the blue stops at 40% and the white begins at 60%. Now it will transition between it.

Comment: You can shorten this to `linear-gradient(to top right, #9999FF 50%, white 50%)`

Comment: shortening it somehow does not achieve the effect.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy your answer helped alot.

Answer (score 1):

Although Jeremy answer is helped me to attain the effect but i had to change it a bit to look like the one in the image.

My Css file:

```
 body{
      height: 100vh;
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom left,#fff 0%, #fff 50%, #8186D5 50%, #8186D5 100%);
    }
```

My HTML file:

```
<body>
</body>
```